# FrameworkEvent ERROR on running a Hello World OSGI Bundle

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, osgi-bundle

I am a beginner in OSGI. I followed the following tutorial to do a simple Hello World OSGI Bundle in eclipse.  http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html?page=2

On running the project, I receive a bunch of errors in the console. Below are these errors:

```
osgi> !SESSION 2013-07-10 23:23:03.340 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/Users/student/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/OSGi Framework/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.ui 4 0 2013-07-10 23:23:08.809
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.startup(LaunchingResourceManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.getLaunchingResourceManager(DebugUIPlugin.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start(DebugUIPlugin.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.startup(LaunchingResourceManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.getLaunchingResourceManager(DebugUIPlugin.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.start(DebugUIPlugin.java:569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2013-07-10 23:23:10.114
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
and other similar errors....
```

Can you please help me to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you followed all instructions correctly? In step 4 of "executing bundle" make sure ONLY your bundle and the system bundle `org.eclipse.osgi` is selected. Uncheck all other bundles and run it

Comment: Yes, I did that, and I think that the commands are working fine on the console. I tried several ones and they worked ok. However, these errors keep displaying. I don't know if I can just ignore them.

Comment: I don't think you did do that. Otherwise why does your application include the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` bundle?

Answer (score 8):

I struggled a lot for **“Workbench has not been created yet”** the complete day.

But I got **the solution by the following steps**.-

1. Go to the **Run configuration** -> Remove all the target platform jars.
2. Click on add required bundles.
3. Check the org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime, org.apache.felix.gogo.shell, org.eclipse.eqinox.console, org.eclipse.osgi and your jar file.
4. The last and important step. Go to **Setting-**> **check** the checkbox of **"Clear the configuratation area before launching**".
5. Run the OSGi application now.
6. Enjoy if it works for you as it worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. This works smooth :)

Answer (score 6):

I am late to the party, but I ran into the exact same problem trying to create the Hello World from javaworld tutorial using eclipse 4.2.

When I deselected all the bundles in the Target Platform and pressed "Add Required Bundles", eclipse only selected

```
org.eclipse.osgi
```

Upon running, I then got the error

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.console
```

Adding the console and pressing "Add Required Bundles" added

```
javax.servlet
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime
org.eclipse.osgi.services
```

along with
org.eclipse.osgi

Running this configuration resulted in

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Missing required bundle: org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
```

Finally, adding

```
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell
```

got me what I expected.

```
Hello World!!
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710
1   ACTIVE      com.javaworld.sample.HelloWorld_1.0.0.qualifier
8   ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
9   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.0.100.v20130429-0953
10  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.0.0.v201112011016
11  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20130513-1956
12  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
osgi>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when you start some unnecessary bundles from your target platform. So only selects the required bundles.

Simply ,while setting the Run Configuration, follow the below steps :

1. In the "bundles" tab, Press Deselect All first.
   This will deselect all the bundles from your workspace and also from the target platform.
2. Now, in the same tab, from the workspace tree structure , do select your own created bundle.
   After this Press the "Add required Bundles".
   This will add the required bundles from the target platform.
   Also you can verify whether all dependencies are satisfied by pressing "Validate Bundles".
3. Now save the configuration and run . Your bundle would be started and all other disturbing bundles will be skipped.

Comment: Your way did not work. It got even worse, more errors and I wasn't able to write any command. Including all bundles in the target platform works fine but shows errors. Did you apply what you are saying?

Comment: @TheTravellingSalesman your comment and downvote are unfair. You should absolutely start only the bundles that are relevant to your application, as suggested by Shinchan (cool name!). If it didn't work for you then it's not his fault... try describing what the actual problems are.

Comment: I know that what @Shinchan said is correct. And I've seen it in tutorials. But his suggestion did not solve my problem. It really got it worse. Maybe because I am doing something else wrong which is what I am trying to understand. Though, maybe I Shouldn't have downvoted him because his answer could be useful to solve other problems. Sorry, but I couldn't upvote him now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I managed to get my bundle to run by creating a new run configuration and deselecting all bundles, adding my bundle and then clicking on Add Required Bundles.

I don't know why this second run configuration works and the first doesn't, I have looked at both .launch files and they are identical.

What seems to be happening is that one run config is running all available bundles even though only three are selected in the gui. If you enter the ss command in the osgi console once all the errors are finished I get 1182 bundles launched for the broken launch config, where as the working config just gives me the correct 3.

You should try to create a new launch config and see if that sorts it, I don't know why the new one works for me but it did, hope this helps.

Output of working config ss:

```
id      State       Bundle
0       ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.dist
                    Fragments=1
1       RESOLVED    javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645
                    Master=0
2       ACTIVE      com.javaworld.sample.HelloWorld_1.0.0.qualifier
```

Last few lines of broken config ss:

```
1040    ACTIVE      org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver_0.15.0.201212080009
1041    ACTIVE      org.testng.eclipse_6.8.0.20121120_1820
1042    ACTIVE      org.uddi4j_2.0.5.v200805270300
1043    ACTIVE      org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.v200805290154
1044    ACTIVE      org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011
1045    ACTIVE      org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433
1046    ACTIVE      org.w3c.sac_1.3.0.v20120213
1155    <<LAZY>>    org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.dist
1182    <<LAZY>>    org.eclipse.equinox.initializer_1.0.0.dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting android:targetSdkVersion="19 solved the problem for me.